# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on project load after SSDT upgraded to 17.4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional on a Windows 10 Enterprise platform. Last week I had to get my machine re-imaged, which of course meant a fresh install of Visual Studio. I have Update 3 applied. So far I have opened one project fine, but the next project I opened has an SSRS project. Now when opening up this project I get the following message box:

[image: Error Message]

When selecting either yes or no, Visual Studio crashes. On viewing the ActivityLog the only error recorded is:

Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{90243340-bd7a-11d0-93ef-00a0c90f2734} Frame caption: Exception details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): The product is not installed properly. Please reinstall. at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

But I have no idea if this is the error or not.

Comment: DId you try what the message suggests? Did you try reinstalling SSDT?

Comment: Yes I have, and I still get the same

Answer (score 0):

Well, who would have known.

The Visual Studio crash is caused because it cannot connect to the database.

I changed the connection string in the config file and it started to work.